# Python script to backup directory via Cron job

Tags: python, cron, nagios

I am trying to run the code below as cronjob without any luck...

```
import sys
import time
import tarfile

def main(argv):
    #f = open('/tmp/backup-log.txt', 'a')
    #f.write('variable start\n')
    timeStamp = time.strftime('%y%m%d')
    nagiosFolder = '/app/nagios/'
    fileName = '/app/nagios_install/backup/nagios-backup-%s.tar.gz' % timeStamp
    #f.write('variable end\n')

    try:
        #f.write('tar start\n')
        tarGeza = tarfile.open(fileName, 'w:gz')
        tarGeza.add(nagiosFolder)
        tarGeza.close()
        #f.write('tar end\n')
        #f.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    except tarfile.TarError, tarexc:
        #f.write('exception error')
        #f.close()
        print tarexc
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The commented sections are for debbuging purposes and whenever the code runs, it shows as the code has finished without errors:

```
variable start
variable end
tar start
tar end
```

My crontab settings are:

```
HOME=/usr/nagios/
LOGNAME=nagios
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/python
SHELL=/usr/bin/python

17 12 * * * /usr/bin/python /app/nagios_install/backup/nagios_backup.py
```

And permissions are the following:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 nagios root 1009 Jan 17 11:00 /app/nagios_install/backup/nagios_backup.py
```

Can anyone please highlight what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clear the initial post...I am able to run the code from CLI, however when it is scheduled via crontab nothing seems to happen..

Comment: You should redirect the output of your cronjob to a log file to capture error messages, for example `17 12 * * * /usr/bin/python /app/nagios_install/backup/nagios_backup.py >> /var/log/nagios_backup.log 2>&1`

Comment: For starters, you certainly don't want the `SHELL` for your crontab to be `/usr/bin/python`, because your command won't make any sense to a python shell (`/usr/bin/python /app/nagios_install/backup/nagios_backup.py`). If that doesn't suffice, you should drop the output in a log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some tips from my end - how I would try to schedule the whole thing

1) Include a `shebang` line at the top of the python script for picking up the python executable and remove the python executable path from the `cron` entry - there is always the off chance that the paths for the executables are different on productions server from development environment.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

2) Change the mode of the script to `755` to make the script executable

```
sudo chmod 755 /app/nagios_install/backup/nagios_backup.py
```

3) Schedule the cron job from the root user's `crontab`

```
sudo crontab -e
```

`crontab -e` opens up current user's crontab by default, and not root user's crontab. And the `nagios` directory may not be acceessible by that current user.

4) Remove the `SHELL` variable from your crontab, it isn't needed in the first place. You are not using variables `LOGNAME`, `HOME` either, so they can also be removed, I don't think they were needed either.

5) Schedule the cron job like following in your root user's crontab

```
17 12 * * * /app/nagios_install/backup/nagios_backup.py >> /var/log/nagios_backup.log 2>&1
```

I think the above setup should work. If it doesn't, try running the script directly and let me know what error(s) it throws.

Comment: This is a very detailed answer! Removing the variables and using the root's crontab did resolve the issue. Thanks very much for your help ansh0l!